# Neo4j: Running multiple script files from cypher shell

Tags: neo4j

In my setup, I have the many cypher files which will be used as part of creating the environment. I believe cypher-shell is the way to install the scripts but I could not find any way to pass multiple files to cypher-shell.

I don't want to write multiple cypher-shell commands passing the different file instead looking for the solution where I can pass a single file which has the path to the other files.

One solution could be combine all files into a single file using the .bat/.sh script and pass that to the cypher-shell....any other solution?

EDIT: The solution which I implemented is to mention the script files in a text file and read the text files line be line and passing the files to the cypher-shell in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher shell is a tool to run cypher scripts. 
I assume you meant reference data when you wrote environment.

Bash shell allows loops like (untested code)

```
for i in $(ls *.cyp);do
  cat $i | cypher-shell -u neo4j -p password
done
```

Comment: The solution which I implemented is to mention the script files in a text file and read the text files line be line and passing the files to the cypher-shell in a loop....thanks for your input.